How Can God Love?
I would like to preface this by saying that my inquiry is 100% unbiased, and I am not very religious.
If God is omnipotent (psalm 115:3), then God is immeasurably perfect in every way. I feel that "human" or "human-like" emotions would detract quite a bit from divine perfection, but does God also love all his creations? Romans 9:13 mentions God's hatred for evil, which he sees in Esau, who he also hates. I understand that God did not directly create evil and sin and it was only a consequence of free will. Even so, the Bible said that God hated not only his actions but he hated Esau himself.
1 John 4:16 - “So we have come to know and to believe the love that God has for us. God is love, and whoever abides in love abides in God, and God abides in him.” God is love, but God is also the embodiment of everything, including hate and other antonyms of love. God is everything because God created everything, and everything he has created is an extension of him (Colossians 1:16).
We can also not answer the question well without defining perfect first. I have always thought of perfection not as the absence of imperfection but as the acceptance and inclusion of everything that makes it. But that isn't everyone's definition, especially not the scriptures (Deuteronomy 32:4). Assuming my opinion is true, there's a straightforward conclusion to God's perfection: God's perfection would include all of his "imperfections," making him perfect but also humane. But in the Bible (Timothy 3:16), he is described as divine without human error. If God were a perfect divine being, how would he feel? Or have any emotions at all? If God is a divine being, I can't understand how he would feel, including his love.
(I apologize in advance if my question isn't framed very well, i'm not very used to translating my thoughts into coherent questions )

Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your excellent question and joining our group.  Please remember to take the tour (link bottom left) to better understand how this site is different.

This is a theological synthesis question, which unfortunately makes it off topic here. Theological questions should instead be asked on the [christianity.se] site, but note that you'd have to specify a denomination/branch whose perspective you desire. Because, for example, Trinitarians and Unitarians would necessarily have quite distinct answers to this question.

The question assumes that love is an emotion. The scripture states that (literally) 'God love is' which expresses an equivalence.

The NT answers this question by asserting that:

1 John 4:7, 8 - Beloved, let us love one another, because love comes from God. Everyone who loves has been born of God and knows God. 8Whoever does not love does not know God, because God is love.
1 John 4:16-19 - And we have come to know and believe the love that God has for us. God is love; whoever abides in love abides in God, and God in him. In this way, love has been perfected among us, so that we may have confidence on the day of judgment; for in this world we are just like Him. There is no fear in love, but perfect love drives out fear, because fear involves punishment. The one who fears has not been perfected in love. We love because He first loved us.
John 13:34, 35 - A new commandment I give you: Love one another. As I have loved you, so you also must love one another. By this everyone will know that you are My disciples, if you love one another.”

The NT writers based these assertions of the essential nature of God on the statements of the OT:

Ps 48:9 - We have thought, O God, on Your lovingkindness, In the midst of Your temple.
Ps 42:8 - The LORD will command His lovingkindness in the daytime, And in the night His song shall be with me— A prayer to the God of my life.
Ps 63:3 - Because Your lovingkindness is better than life, My lips shall praise You.
Ps 63:7 - I will make known the LORD’s loving devotion and His praiseworthy acts, because of all that the LORD has done for us—the many good things for the house of Israel according to His great compassion and loving devotion.
Ps 89:33 - Nevertheless My lovingkindness I will not utterly take from him, Nor allow My faithfulness to fail.
Ps 92:2 - To declare Your lovingkindness in the morning, And Your faithfulness every night,

Now, this is all very well but the other side of this coin is obvious - the love supremely is to hate evil:

Ps 45:7 - You love righteousness and hate wickedness; therefore God, your God, has set you above your companions by anointing you with the oil of joy.
Ps 5:4 - For You are not a God who delights in wickedness; no evil can dwell with You.
Prov 8:13 - To fear the LORD is to hate evil; I hate pride and arrogance, evil behavior and perverse speech.
Ps 97:10 - Let those who love the LORD hate evil, for he guards the lives of his faithful ones and delivers them from the hand of the wicked.
Zech 8:17 - do not plot evil in your hearts against your neighbor, and do not love to swear falsely, for I hate all these things,” declares the LORD.

Thus, God loves all people but hates sin and will finally eradicate all sin from the universe.

Rev 21:1 - Then I saw a new heaven and a new earth, for the first heaven and earth had passed away, and the sea was no more.
Nahum 1:9 - Whatever you plot against the LORD, He will bring to an end. Affliction will not rise up a second time.

Until that time, let serve the Lord with gladness by faith and trust His trustworthiness and say with those who seek God -

Isa 25:9 - In that day they will say, “Surely this is our God; we trusted in him, and he saved us. This is the LORD, we trusted in him; let us rejoice and be glad in his salvation.”

How does God's love work for us?

Rom 5:6, 8 - For at just the right time, while we were still
powerless, Christ died for the ungodly. ... But God proves His love
for us in this: While we were still sinners, Christ died for us.


I suppose I meant the inquiry in a more of a secular way to question how his love could be possible in the first place, instead of what his love is.

Thank you, this helps me with a lot of context!

@sofi - Rom 5:6, 8 - For at just the right time, while we were still powerless, Christ died for the ungodly. ... But God proves His love for us in this: While we were still sinners, Christ died for us.

This was a clear theological question, not exegetical. Please don't answer off topic questions. It seems especially misleading considering your comment reminding the asker to take the tour to understand how this site is different...

@curiousdannii - my apologies for offending you - but I did not recognize this as theological and answered with almost no "theology" but a series of texts on the topic to provide context.  I also thought that this would be very uncontroversial.

This post is definitely theology, I'm confused how you'd think otherwise haha. What do you think theology is if it wouldn't include this? In any case, the issue is not your answer, but that the question isn't asking about the interpretation of any passage, but instead for a theological conclusion based on synthesising many passages together.
